# How do I properly use the 'state' parameter of BeginRead?

Tags: .net, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, c#-4.0

If I have `NetworkStream.BeginRead(DataBuffer, 0, DataBuffer.Size,  MyAsyncCallback, MyObject)`, where `MyObject` is a class containing `DataBuffer` and `NetworkStream`, how can I access `MyObject` from `MyAsyncCallback`?

The goal is to use `MyAsyncCallback` to update `MyObject` with the information `BeginRead` places in `DataBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

All that's required to get original `MyObject` is a cast.

```
MyObject o = (MyObject)ar.AsyncState;
```

where `ar` is a `MyAsyncCallback` parameter.